# Can you do "git branch -r" in libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

In LibGit2Sharp, is it possible to do the equivalent of "git branch -r"--that is, see the list names of all the remote branches on a repo, even those not yet tracked locally? I can't find anything in LibGit2Sharp's documentation that indicates if this can be done.

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-branch

Answer (score 0):

Check the test [`NetworkFixture`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/f8e2d42ed9051fa5a5348c1a13d006f0cc069bc7/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/NetworkFixture.cs#L25-L44): it lists remote references, which is the equivalent of a [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote): that is how you list remote branches even if you don't track them yet (like the references listed in [`TestRemoteRefs.cs`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/f8e2d42ed9051fa5a5348c1a13d006f0cc069bc7/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/TestRemoteRefs.cs#L6-L18)):

```
IList<Reference> references = repo.Network.ListReferences(remote).ToList();
List<Tuple<string, string>> actualRefs = 
  references.Select(directRef => new Tuple<string, string>(directRef.CanonicalName, directRef.ResolveToDirectReference().TargetIdentifier)).ToList();
```